# Troubleshooting Admin_Notice

Tags: plugins, notices

I have this code at the top of a plugin:

```
 function my_mwe_admin_notice(){
    echo '<div class="notice notice-error">';
    echo '<h1>Notice this.</h1>';
    echo '</div>';
 }
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_mwe_admin_notice' );
```

Where and when is this notice supposed to appear?

I can't find it.

Have also tried adding `global $pagenow` and `if ( 'plugins.php' == $pagenow ) { // also index.php, etc...`

What am I missing?

Comment: It will appear only in the back end, in wp-admin at the top of any page, not on the front end.

Comment: Ha ha. I know that. You mean in the admin console, right? The above code should display `<h1>Notice this.</h1>` on every page in the admin, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes. btw - tested your code and it works properly.

Comment: Any ideas for troubleshooting why it's not working on my dev env?

Comment: No. Is the rest of the plugin working?

Comment: Fully working. I thought maybe there was a setting somewhere like the global to DISABLE_NAG notices (I forget what it's called). Frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup. I threw my test code in the top of the Hello Dolly plugin and there was the notice.

That's when I remembered that I was calling it within a namespace:

So needed to referenced that so the WP action could access it:

```
namespace My_Plugin;

function my_mwe_admin_notice(){
    echo '<div class="notice notice-error">';
    echo '<h1>Notice this.</h1>';
    echo '</div>';
 }
add_action( 'admin_notices', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\my_mwe_admin_notice' );
```